# Hibernate @ManyToOne calling itself

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, orm

I have this entity Messages with has the property "parent" this property is also type Message. The is create a message with parent=null and the messages with parent=message will be a comment, so then I have a tree message and comments.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message extends BaseModel{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
    private User user;

    private String text;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "message_id",nullable = true)
    private Message parent;
```

however when I try to save my entity here the code:

```
 Message message = messageRepository.save(
                MapperUtils.getInstance().map(messageDTO,Message.class)
        );
```

I always get this message:

> org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property 
>   references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before
>   current operation : gara.models.Message.user -> gara.models.User;
>   nested   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property
>   references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before
>   current operation : gara.models.Message.user -> gara.models.User"

How I could fixed it or there is a work around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error tells the solution. You are setting the User dependency with an unmanaged / detached object.

Make sure that you populate the Message with User that is already in the persistence context (for example by using the repo method):

```
userRepository.getOne(id); // just get the reference
```

or, if the user is not yet in the db.. `userRepository.save`, or set the cascade option on the relationship:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
private User user;
```

The same case may be with the `parent` self-dependency.

Comment: You are right I also saw that this line: MapperUtils.getInstance().map(messageDTO,Message.class) parse the object without the user->id property so ... there the error